# Intellij angular detects errors in html that does not exist

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea

Intellij detects errors in the html which does not exist as if it did not take into account the node modules, of course the project is fully functional it is just the IDE which displays these errors.

[image: Intellij errors]

Here are the types of error it shows :

```
Attribute baseChart is not allowed here
```

```
Property data is not provided by any applicable directives nor by canvas element
```

---

I know leaving errors doesn't change anything in the project but it's quite confusing to have to code with this.

Comment: what IDE and Angular versions do you use?

Comment: My IDE version is 2021.1 and Angular version is 14.1.0 @lena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the new Angular package format introduced in Angular 13 is available since IDE version 2021.3 (see [WEB-53312](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53312/Support-Angular-13)); Angular 14 support ([standalone components](https://blog.angular.io/an-update-on-standalone-components-ea53b4d55214), etc.) is added in version 2022.2. To be able to work with the recent Angular versions, please consider upgrading IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Because The name of selector component is the same with native `<canvas>` element.
If you don't want it to show as error you can edit configuration by:

`Settings/Preferences > Inspections > Angular > Undefined bidding`

and change `Severity` from Error to any other type, but this way it will cause to all of cases even it truly wrong.